# Netflix API - alter video?

Tags: python, video, graphics, netflix

So I would like to know if there is any way to alter the video that is playing on netflix, through writing a script or a plug-in for the service.

An example:
22 minute show. Let's say I want to skip the first 2 minutes and continue the video from there. I mean, there has to be some kind of way to do this, I expect it to be

`if(video.play) then video.play(timestamp)`

or something like 
`if(colorcode) then skip.frame();` or whatever.

Comment: You'd better be quick... http://developer.netflix.com/blog/read/Retiring_the_Netflix_Public_API

Comment: Your question is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/q/6086205/21945 .

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight playback, you can get a reference on the video object that their site uses with the following JavaScript (i.e. using something like TamperMonkey):

```
var vp = netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer(); 
vp.seek(60500); // in milliseconds
```

Refer to the ending comment in [Controlling Netflix playback with TamperMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927950/controlling-netflix-playback-with-tampermonkey) as well.