# Controlling the Netflix player manually with .seek() method

Tags: javascript, netflix

I'm looking to seek the Netflix player manually (from the console).
I get the player : `netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer()`, and I know there is a `.seek()` method on it but I don't know how to use it.

What I've tried

```
netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer().seek(60)
netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer().seek("60")
```

& nothing happens...

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work?  Found an older thread that indicated this was possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086205/javascript-api-for-netflix-instant-player

Comment: Appears removed now, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927950/controlling-netflix-html5-playback-with-tampermonkey-javascript for follow up discussion

Answer (score 1):

The `netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer().seek()` function accepts a time in milliseconds. Assuming your argument was in seconds, you can fix this by calling `.seek(60 * 1000)` to seek one minute into the video.

For future reference, most time-related functions in JavaScript will either accept or return a number in milliseconds such as `setTimeout()` and `Date.getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

I did:`bgMusic2.SeekTo( 0 );`
So try changing seek to SeekTo( number here );
One very usefull tool for learning stuff like this is an app called DroidScript.

Comment: thanks for your response but I'm pretty sure the method to use is `.seek()`