# Load subtitles to Netflix player

Tags: javascript

Someone know how to load own subtitles to Netflix player like SuperFlix do? There is only few infromations about Netflix HTML5 player, one of those is that I should can manipulate player using
       `netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer();`
and so one, but 
`Uncaught TypeError: netflix.cadmium.objects.videoPlayer is not a function(…)` is the only thing I got. I suppose that Netflix changes something, but SuperFlix still works so it's possible. Iam trying it in Chrome console but in the end it would be Chrome extension.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling Netflix playback with Tampermonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927950/controlling-netflix-playback-with-tampermonkey)

Answer (score 3):

Despite it being referenced [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931627/1095883), I also can't find a property on `cadmium` called `videoPlayer` therefore it may **no longer exist**, being deprecated from the API.

But I used..

```
for(var prop in netflix) { 
    if(netflix.hasOwnProperty(prop)) console.log(prop); 
}
```

..to find that `netflix` now has a `video` property. Use the above code in conjunction with the web inspector to reverse engineer their framework and you'll find the updated function call you're after. This should help get you started.

Good luck

Comment: video property seems to also no longer exist anymore [?] FWIW :|

Comment: This is what you can expect when building atop a private and undocumented API ;)

Answer (score 0):

In fact the only thing that SuperFlix does is simulate the pressing of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on browser, the Netflix's player already have the function of loading your own subtitle.

Despite that, I developed a chrome extension that allows multiples subtitles on Netflix. It works based on HTML 5 video element. [Worth a try](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/subtitles-for-netflix/oddfihdjoneffhjjlpgdjaefeklefmdi?authuser=1)!

Comment: How were you able to access the subtitles for your extension? Does it still work?